# mysqladmin error while attempting to install MediaWiki on 14.10

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I've been following this installation guide for MediaWiki on Ubuntu (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Running_MediaWiki_on_Ubuntu#Step-By-Step) and I managed to get up to **Configure MySQL->Regular Setup** before I received an error. See I ran

```
mysqladmin -u root password "..."
```

(where ... is my password) in the terminal and received the error:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

I then tried changing `root` in this command to my username and this too failed. I then ran `mysql_secure_installation` to ensure I had my username & password right, I didn't so I changed my password and re-ran this command (with `root` this time, not my username) and this failed, again. Any idea of how I can overcome this error?

Comment: The tutorial assumes no MySQL root password is set when you run this command. If a password exists already, the correct format is `mysqladmin -u root -p "<oldpassword>" password "<newpassword>"`. Of course if a password exists already, running this command is fairly pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i've read on that tutorial is this:

> This step is not necessary if you were prompted to create a mysql root password during MySQL installation.

I recently reinstalled `lamp` and i remember having been prompted for `MySQL` root password during the installation. Most likely you have set your password already. If you don't remember having done so, try to change the password to a new one assuming that the default password ('') has been used:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p '' password '<new_password>'
```

Comment: Well that seemed to be working until I got to the localhost stage where now I'm getting this error indicating that mysql isn't working right: http://i.imgur.com/Es6oA6G.png. Oh and btw I have installed `php5-mysql` (I even tried reinstalling it by `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`).

Comment: @BrentonHorne Try this: `locate mysql.so`. It should show the path of of `mysql.so`. Then do `sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. Look if those two lines are present: `extensions_dir=<some_path>` and `extension=mysql.so`. If they're present, uncomment them (if commented) and make sure that <some_path> corresponds to the path of mysql.so. If they're not present, add them.

Comment: @BrentonHorne By the way i believe the two issues are different and separate, and i think you should ask a new question for the second problem

Comment: The locate command gave this: `/home/fusion809/mediawiki-1.24.1-0/common/lib/apr-util-1/apr_dbd_mysql.so
/home/fusion809/mediawiki-1.24.1-0/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so
/usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/mysql.so
/usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/pdo_mysql.so` so I'm not sure as to which I should add to php.ini

Comment: I added a new question like you suggested (http://askubuntu.com/questions/591249/mediawiki-installation-error-mysql-not-identified)