# MediaWiki installation error: MySQL not identified

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

After following this answer [mysqladmin error while attempting to install MediaWiki on 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590928/mysqladmin-error-while-attempting-to-install-mediawiki-on-14-10/590936#590936) I received this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i86Hw.png. I have been recommended to do:

`local mysql.so`

and add the output (presumably singular) to php.ini but this command gave five distinct file outputs:

```
/home/fusion809/mediawiki-1.24.1-0/common/lib/apr-util-1/apr_dbd_mysql.so 
/home/fusion809/mediawiki-1.24.1-0/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock 
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so
/usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/mysql.so 
/usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/pdo_mysql.so
```

So I'm not sure which I should add.

Plus what is meant by commenting/uncommenting `extension_dir` and `extension` from this php.ini file? Currently this line exists in php.ini:

```
; extension_dir = "./"
```

and this extension line:

```
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is the one you want: `/usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/mysql.so`

Uncommenting in this case means removing the semicolon. Whitespaces are not required, so this one:

```
;   extension=msql.so
```

Should become this one:

```
extension=mysql.so
```

(notice the missing `y` in the original)

And this one:

```
; extension_dir = "./"
```

Should become this one:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/"
```

Notice that this prevents other `PHP` extensions to be added using additional `extension=<extension>.so` lines in `php.ini` (unless the related static library is present in `/usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/`), so if you need more extensions you should workaround a way to have all the extensions in a (possibly new) unique folder (i.e.: copying all static libraries needed in such folder)